# igraph: subsetting edges with iterators

Tags: igraph

Suppose I have an igraph object

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 0.6)
```

and I get the minimum spanning tree

```
min.span <- minimum.spanning.tree(g)
```

How can I get the edges of g that are part of the minimum spanning tree using iterators E() or V()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just mark the edges in the original graph with an edge attribute. E.g.

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 0.6)
E(g)$mark <- seq_len(ecount(g))
min.span <- minimum.spanning.tree(g)
E(min.span)$mark
#> [1]  1  2  3  6  8 10 12 15 19 22 26 32 42 52 62 67 76 84 94
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the best solution as I'm not too familiar with R, but this seems to do the trick for me:

```
> mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(g)
> eids <- get.edge.ids(g, as.vector(t(get.edgelist(mst))))
> E(g)[eids]
```